# How to determine the source vertex of connected component in graphx

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I'm trying to determine the source vertex (root) in each connected component. The Graphx documentation says the connected components algorithm labels each connected component of the graph with the ID of its lowest-numbered vertex.

[image]

I would like to retrieve the source vertex, in this case 11. How can I do that?

Comment: Didn't you just give the answer? The label of cluster will be the label of the lowest-numbered vertex. Isn't that what you are looking for? If not, then I am not sure what you mean as "root" in a connected component.

Comment: @marios thanks for the quick reply, appreciate...just added a digram.

Comment: From my understanding, `root` of tree is a vertex with `0 InDegree` and `>0 OutDegree`. So just find such vertex.

Comment: I don't think this is well formulated in the context of connected components. Cc are no necessarily DAGs so in your example you can have node 3 connected to node 11. In that case what is your root?